# int instanceof Integer

Tags: java, instanceof, autoboxing

Why this is a compile-time error when Java does the Autoboxing? Am I missing something?

```
int primitiveIntVariable = 0;

if (primitiveIntVariable instanceof Integer) {

}
```

I get

```
Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'int' to 'java.lang.Integer'
```

Comment: As the name suggests, instanceof means an instance (object) of a class. Primitive datatypes are not instances.

Comment: Just because java is able to automatically convert an int to an Integer, doesnt mean that the int itself is actually an Integer. But that is what you are testing here.

Comment: *"when Java does the Autoboxing"* Why do you believe Java would do auto-boxing in that statement? Autoboxing only happens in [*assignment contexts*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2), [*invocation contexts*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3), and [*casting contexts*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5). It does not happen in the middle of an *expression*, and `instanceof` is an expression operator.

Answer (score 10):

As the name suggests, instanceof means an instance (object) of a class. Primitive datatypes are not instances.

This is how you get the class for a primitive datatype:

```
int i = 1;
System.out.println(((Object)i).getClass().getName());
// prints: java.lang.Integer
```

So instead of instanceof, use isInstance(...) like this:

```
Integer.class.isInstance(1); // returns true
Integer.class.isInstance(1.2); // returns false
```

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: Note that your solution does not test the `int` itself but autoboxxes it into `Integer` first (since the method expects an object and not an int)

Comment: Down-voted because doing `Integer.class.isInstance(1)` makes no sense, so is not a useful thing to do. Java is type-safe, so there is absolutely no way it could be false, so why even do the test? Why convert a *primitive* (which is not an object) to an object (using compiler auto-boxing) to check if it some particular king of object. It's *not an object*, so the check is ludicrous.

Comment: Not ludicrous at all.  That was a simple example that may not be useful as is, but it is helpful when you have a collection of objects and need to treat int differently from another type.

Answer (score 5):

`int` cannot be anything but an `int`, so the entire concept of using `instanceof` is meaningless, and misguided.

You only use `instanceof` if you need to check if the actual object is a particular type different from the type of the variable in question (or known supertypes hereof).

E.g. if the declared type of the variable (or the return value, or the compile-type of expression), is `Integer`, then it makes no sense whatsoever to check it is an `instanceof` of `Integer`. Given that Java is type-safe, you already ***know*** that it is.

Similarly, it makes no sense whatsoever to check if a known `Integer` is an `instanceof` of `Number`. You already ***know*** that it is.

And it makes even less sense to check if a known `int` is an `instanceof` of `Integer`. It's a *primitive*, and you know it is, so there is absolutely no way it can be an instance of any object type.

The last will generate a compiler error. The first two examples are compiler warnings, which is very evident if you use any good IDE. Always use a good IDE, because they catch so many dumb mistakes we all happen to write occasionally.

---

So the above was an explanation of why it makes no sense to even try, but even though `integerVar instanceof Integer` makes no sense, it compiles ok, but `intVar instanceof Integer` fails to compile, so why it that?

The reason is actually related to this mistaken statement in the question:

> when Java does the Autoboxing

Java doesn't do autoboxing everywhere. Autoboxing only happens in:

- [*assignment contexts*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2), e.g. `Integer x = 5`
- [*invocation contexts*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3), e.g. `foo(5)` where parameter is an `Integer`
- [*casting contexts*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5), e.g. `(Integer) 5` or `(Object) 5`

It does not happen by itself in the *middle* of an expression, and `instanceof` is an expression operator.

But, more specifically, it fails to compile because JLS [15.20.2. Type Comparison Operator `instanceof`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2) says so:

> **RelationalExpression `instanceof` ReferenceType**
>
> The type of the *RelationalExpression* operand of the `instanceof` operator **must be a reference type** or the null type, or a compile-time error occurs.