# instanceOf Integer fails for a number in Object

Tags: java

I have this mutable document that I get from a function...contents unknown. But for simplicity, I am creating a sample document:

```
     MutableDocument doc = new MutableDocument();
     doc.setString("l", "j");
     doc.setInt("v", 20);
      
     List<String> keys = doc.getKeys();
     for(i = 0; i< 2; i++){
        Object v = doc.getValue(i);
        if (v instanceOf String){
         //finds l correctly
         }else if (v instanceOf Integer){
             //nothing happens here
           }
      }
```

from this: [int instanceof Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57742606/int-instanceof-integer), I noticed int is not Integer but how would I go handling the above condition?

Update: thanks all. I just did value.getClass() and it is indeed Long.

Comment: It would be an `Integer` as it’s boxed. I don’t know what a `MutableDocument` is but are you sure it gives you an `Integer`, not - say - a `Double`?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What is `MutableDocument`? Can you provide its implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Well, `v` is already an `Integer` rather than an `int`.

It depends on how exactly your `setInt` and `getValue` methods are implemented, but in any case, `v` cannot be an `int` in the line below:

```java
Object v = doc.getValue(i);
```

That is because an `int` cannot be stored into an `Object`, as an `int` is a primitive type. Instead, it is autoboxed into an `Integer`.

---

<sup>By the way, since `getValue` could return a `String` judging by your code, it cannot also return a primitive type. So `getValue` *must* return an `Object`. When the method returns, the value of what once was an `int`, is guaranteed to be autoboxed into an `Integer`.</sup>